# socket_sendto(): unable to write to socket [1]: Operation not permitted while using papertrail logging

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use papertrail as the logging channel in my laravel 8.X application. Whenever I use the following statement, it is throwing an exception

```
  Log::channel('papertrail')->info('Something happened!');
```

> socket_sendto(): unable to write to socket [1]: Operation not permitted

```
vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/SyslogUdp/UdpSocket.php:52
     

    public function write($line, $header = "")

    {

        $this->send($this->assembleMessage($line, $header));

    }

 

    public function close(): void

    {

        if (is_resource($this->socket)) {

            socket_close($this->socket);

            $this->socket = null;

        }

    }

 

    protected function send(string $chunk): void

    {

        if (!is_resource($this->socket)) {

            throw new \RuntimeException('The UdpSocket to '.$this->ip.':'.$this->port.' has been closed and can not be written to anymore');

        }

        socket_sendto($this->socket, $chunk, strlen($chunk), $flags = 0, $this->ip, $this->port);

    }

 

    protected function assembleMessage(string $line, string $header): string

    {

        $chunkSize = static::DATAGRAM_MAX_LENGTH - strlen($header);

 

        return $header . Utils::substr($line, 0, $chunkSize);

    }

}
```

Please advice.

Comment: Does `php-fpm` have write access to the log file? Check your directory permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because the log info you are sending is too big. (It probably works most of the time, but some larger errors are too big).

Laravel is using by default UDP to send the log to Papertrail.

The Papertrail accepts logs that UDP packets of up to 1024 bytes / TCP that are up to 100,000 bytes (~100 KB) long.
https://www.papertrail.com/help/troubleshooting-remote-syslog-reachability/#message-length

A solution is to use TCP. Since Laravel 9 there is an env variable to override this:
`LOG_PAPERTRAIL_HANDLER = SocketHandler::class logging.php`

For older versions of Laravel, you can override the config/logging.php to use the `SocketHandler::class` in stead of the `SyslogUdpHandler::class`.

**Remark:** not all shared hosting providers allow to make a TLS connection.

Comment: Thank you! This should be filed as a bug in laravel, because random exceptions can cause these undecipherable errors.